# Immersion for men: pool vs. mikvah

Tags: shabbat, mikvah-ritual-bath

For men wishing to immerse ion Erev Shabbos, is there a benefit to going to a Mikvah that was made for purposes of tevilah, vs. using a standard pool?

Comment: Why do they want to immerse? That will make a big difference to understanding what benefits they might appreciate

Comment: Extra kedusha for Shabbos.

Comment: I don't know what that is or how a mikva accomplishes that, but as best you can define what is being sought please [edit] your question to clarify

Comment: Anecdotally, immersion in a body of water (if you live near an ocean kudos to you- find a spot where you are alone from others and immerse) that is found outside in nature might be even more awesome than in a small confined mikvah or swimming pool. From myself I remember tremendous benefits of doing that (immersion either in a small pond in midst of a forest or a flowing river on Friday afternoon during the hot summer days).

Answer (score 1):

See here an answer here:

https://dinonline.org/2010/06/29/using-pool-as-mikva/

> It is preferable to immerse in a rabbinically approved mikva; however, when such a mikva is not available, or under extenuating circumstances, is it acceptable to use a swimming pool as a mikvah.

> This answer is specifically for men, for whom immersion is only a “custom.” Women must always immerse only in a rabbinically approved mikva.

Comment: This is not correct. Immersion for both men and women can be customary or obligatory. You should clarify what mikvaot serve what purposes directly and not speak of irrelevant factors like gender

Comment: If you are quoting someone else's words you have to indicate that they are someone else's.

Comment: How do make it like that?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: The OP mentioned men so his question was gender related. Please explain how a man can have an obligation to immerse nowadays.

Comment: That's easy, suppose he is a kohen who wants to eat challa in the diaspora or he is going to go up on the Temple Mount in areas outside the Cheil or even inside the Cheil for a soldier who is there for pikuach nefesh (or maybe he's a Zav or Boel Nidda and wants to weaken his ability to impart Tumah, perhaps useful for a farmer who wants to not Metammei his Tevel or something). Do you also not know how women can go to the mikva as only a custom? The question did mention a gender but that doesn't make the disclaimer in this post any less inaccurate.

Comment: A women goes to the mikvah as a custom on erev yom kippur in many communities as is brought in Mishna Berura

Comment: In public conversation it is left as gender related to avoid spelling it out I believe.

Comment: Bingo! For completeness, I'll mention she could also go on Friday for "Extra kedusha for Shabbos" if she wanted to, though again I haven't a clue what that means.

Comment: Instead of avoiding spelling out the facts by writing something inaccurate, why not just spell out the facts by saying something accurate? I don't understand.